# What happen to Kompozer? Is there an easy way to install in 13.10?

Tags: installation, development, html

What happen to Kompozer? Is there an easy way to install it in Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Install the dependencies**:

```
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libidl0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango1.0-0 libpng12-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libxft2 libxinerama1 libxrender1 libxt6 zlib1g
```

**32 bit systems**:

*Download the packages*

```
wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb

wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb

wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

*Install the packages and fix the broken dependencies, if any*:

```
sudo dpkg -i kompozer*.deb

sudo apt-get install -f
```

**64 bit systems**:

*Download the packages*

```
wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb

wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb

wget -c https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

*Install the packages and fix the broken dependencies, if any*:

```
sudo dpkg -i kompozer*.deb

sudo apt-get install -f
```

[Source](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-kompozer-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04/)

Comment: If you use `gdebi` in place of `dpkg -i`, it usually sorts out the dependencies the way `apt-get` sort of does.

Comment: I didn't have to install the dependencies for 13.10

Comment: Many thanks! I had found this site too after doing a bit more searching: http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=565206&p=4492077#p4452436 But I do not speak Italian ;)

Comment: @Wilf Thanks for gdebi hint. First I used it ... worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it installed.

To install Kompozer, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

For 32-bit, run the following commands:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

For 64-bit, run the following commands:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i kompozer-data_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb kompozer-dev_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_all.deb kompozer_0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu Sharing](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-kompozer-in-ubuntu-13-04-12-10)</sup>