# Error while installing Kompozer

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, 32-bit

I am trying to install kompozer by following  https://askubuntu.com/a/423070/283650.

But in last step it  shows following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package kompozer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up kompozer-data (1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kompozer-dev:
 kompozer-dev depends on kompozer (>= 1:0.8~b3.dfsg.1-0.1ubuntu2); however:
  Package kompozer is not configured yet.`

dpkg: error processing package kompozer-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:
 kompozer
 kompozer-dev
```

Comment: Add the full error message in your question

Comment: @A.B. you can have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library `libidl0` is in the Ubuntu repositories for your Ubuntu version 15.04.

Therefore

```
sudo apt install libidl0
```

<sup>Yes, you can use `apt` since Vivid</sup>